# How to add multiple audio files to specific time in a video using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to add 2 audio files each at 10 and 15 seconds after the video playback.

I used the following command, but the output video plays both audio files at the same time after 10 seconds:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 \ 
-itsoffset 10 -i audio1.mp3 \
-itsoffset 15 -i audio2.mp3 \
-filter_complex amix -map 0:v -map 1:a -map 2:a \
-c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental output.mp4
```

How can I make the 2 files play at 10 and 15 seconds each after the video playback?

Answer (score 3):

yes the solution is using `-async 1`
I have added a general formula when adding N audio to video
use amix filter with inputs=N+1

**example:**
I have added 4 audios to one video

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -itsoffset 10 -i note1.mp3 -itsoffset 15 -i note2.mp3 -itsoffset 90.7 -i note3.mp3 -itsoffset 120.58 -i note4.mp3 -filter_complex amix=inputs=5[a] -map 0:v -map [a] -c:v copy -async 1 -c:a aac output.mp4
```

Comment: @abdullah_nouraldaim Do you know how to also remove the original audio of the video ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I had to add `-async 1` to the command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 \ 
-itsoffset 10 -i audio1.mp3 \
-itsoffset 15 -i audio2.mp3 \
-filter_complex amix -map 0:v -map 1:a -map 2:a \
-c:v copy -async 1 -c:a aac -strict experimental output.mp4
```

Now it works fine!

Comment: For some reason, your method only works for the first offset audio file, the second one is not working for me.

Comment: @zack_lee Do you know how to also remove the original audio of the video ?

Answer (score 1):

Abdullah Nouraldaim's answer above is working great for me if I want to keep the original sound from the video.

But in case you want to remove sound from the original video, you can run the modified version below!

```
ffmpeg -y -an -i video.mp4 -itsoffset 10 -i note1.mp3 -itsoffset 15 -i note2.mp3 -itsoffset 90.7 -i note3.mp3 -itsoffset 120.58 -i note4.mp3 -filter_complex amix=inputs=4[a] -map 0:v -map [a] -c:v copy -async 1 -c:a aac output.mp4
```

Modifications:

1. add `-an` before `video.mp4` to remove its audio stream
2. change `amix=inputs=5[a]` to `amix=inputs=4[a]` because after removing audio stream from our `video.mp4`, there are now only 4 audio streams.